# Add other option to checkbox in Pardot

Tags: forms, webforms

I'm wondering if it's possible to add an "other " option to a checkbox in a pardot form. Users would have to be able to type any other option they want

Example:
I am interested in:

1) Basketball

2) Soccer

3) Golf

4)  < textbox for an "other" option >

Is this feature build in to pardot or would i have use some logic afterwards and use a seperate textbox ( if textbox is filled in, ignore checkbox and take value of the textbox )

Answer (score 0):

You could do this out of the box using "Dependent fields" if your fields were dropdown or text type.

In your case (using checkboxes) it will have to be new custom field to capture the "other" response and a little bit of javascript or jquery to show/hide this field when the "other" checkbox was selected.

Answer (score 0):

According to Pardot, dependent fields can only be based on text or dropdown field types.

In order to have the dependent field option, you may need to switch the field type from checkbox to dropdown, if that's an option in your case.

If it is, you will need to create an extra prospect field for the other option textbox, like Interests_Other, that will only show up when the "Other" option is selected.

http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2128374-form-field-options-reference#dependent-fields

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.